# Memory leak in CcomObject

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, com

I am working on a memory leak and identified there is a leak in ummanaged code. Using UMDH, we found that the below code is having the leak:

```
+   36608 (  67704 -  31096)    651 allocs  BackTraceAF008B48
+     352 (    651 -    299)    BackTraceAF008B48   allocations

    ntdll!RtlpCallInterceptRoutine+3F
    ntdll!RtlpAllocateHeapInternal+9E0
    MSVCR100!malloc+5B (f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\malloc.c, 89)
    mfc100!operator new+3E
    !ATL::CComObject<CCoreTimeoutObject>::CreateInstance+66 (c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atlcom.h, 2907)
    !CMyClass::GetTimeoutObject+48 (cmyclass.cpp, 1813)
    <no module>!???+0 : 7FFD68AC259D

STDMETHODIMP CMyClass::GetTimeoutObject(/* [out] */ IMyInterface **ppTimeoutObj)
  {
      ATLASSERT(ppTimeoutObj && !(*ppTimeoutObj));
  
      CComObject<CCoreTimeoutObject> *pTimeoutObj = NULL;
      HRESULT hr = CComObject<CCoreTimeoutObject>::CreateInstance(&pTimeoutObj);
      if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
      {
          *ppTimeoutObj = static_cast<IMyInterface *>(pTimeoutObj);
          (*ppTimeoutObj)->AddRef();
      }
  
      return hr;
  }
```

EDIT: Adding the place where it is called.

This method is called from 2 places. One from managed code, and the other one from unmanaged code.

Managed code:

```
MYLib.IFlow mySvc = (MyLib.IFlow)MyServices.MySvcCOM;
mySvc.GetTimeoutObject(out _hardwareDoneRecieved);
```

But there is no code to make the `_hardwareDoneReceived` to be null. So I hope this is the leak here?

Unmanaged code:

```
STDMETHODIMP CSourceBase::get_CoreTimeoutObject( /* [retval][out] */ IUnknown **ppTimeoutObj)
{    
    return GetLocalSvc()->GetTimeoutObject(ppTimeoutObj);
}
```

I hope there is no leak in the calling part of unmanaged code!!

Comment: There is no leak in this code.  The code that calls `GetTimeoutObject()` is responsible for calling `Release()` on the returned `IMyInterface` when done using it, eg: `IMyInterface *intf; GetTimeoutObject(&intf); ... intf->Release();` The log you showed is telling you where the leaked memory was originally allocated. That implies that `Release()` has not been called.

Comment: `CComObject` is a managed pointer (interface) class. So `CComObject<CCoreTimeoutObject> *pTimeoutObj = NULL;` is strange and looses the benefit of having a managed pointer.

Comment: @RichardCritten you are probably thinking of [`CComPtr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/ccomptr-class?view=msvc-170), which is a smart pointer for COM interface pointers. [`CComObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/ccomobject-class?view=msvc-170), on the other hand, is a base class for implementing COM objects.

Comment: Additionally best practice is not to static_cast between interfaces but to use `CComObject::QueryInterface` to obtain the new interface.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That I am - everyone else please ignore my ramblings.

Comment: This code here is fine. This is where the object is created, but it's supposed to be created here. You need to find out why it doesn't get deleted. Find the code that calls this function. Find why that code doesn't delete it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau. I added the code which calls this method. For the code part which called from managed code, I think we need to make the object to null. From the unmanaged calling part, is there any leak in it?

Comment: @StackUser you did not show the code that is calling `get_CoreTimeoutObject()`, so we can't determine if *that* caller is leaking or not.

Answer (score 0):

In the *managed* code, `mySvc` and `_hardwareDoneRecieved` should release their interfaces automatically when they go out of scope.  There should be no leak there.

However, in the *unmanaged* code, I do see some problems.

You did not show the implementation of `GetLocalSvc()`, so that is a *potential* leak, depending on what it actually returns.  For instance, if it returns an `AddRef`'ed interface, then `get_CoreTimeoutObject()` (and any other caller) will need to `Release()` it.

But more importantly, `CMyClass::GetTimeoutObject()` takes a `IMyInterface**` but `CSourceBase::get_CoreTimeoutObject()` is giving `GetTimeoutObject()` an `IUnknown**` instead, so you have a type mismatch that shouldn't even compile.

Either `get_CoreTimeoutObject()` should output a `IMyInterface**`:

```cpp
STDMETHODIMP CSourceBase::get_CoreTimeoutObject( /* [retval][out] */ IMyInterface **ppTimeoutObj)
{    
    return GetLocalSvc()->GetTimeoutObject(ppTimeoutObj);

    // or, if needed:
    //
    // CComPtr<IFlow> svc;
    // svc.Attach(GetLocalSvc());
    // return svc->GetTimeoutObject(ppTimeoutObj);
}
```

Or, it should call `GetTimeoutObject()` with a local `IMyInterface*` and then call `QueryInterface()` on it to get its `IUnknown*` (and then `Release()` the local).

```cpp
STDMETHODIMP CSourceBase::get_CoreTimeoutObject( /* [retval][out] */ IUnknown **ppTimeoutObj)
{    
    CComPtr<IMyInterface> intf;
    HRESULT hr = GetLocalSvc()->GetTimeoutObject(&intf);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = intf->QueryInterface(IID_IUnknown, reinterpret_cast<void**>(ppTimeoutObj));
    }
    return hr;

    // or, if needed:
    //
    // CComPtr<IFlow> svc;
    // svc.Attach(GetLocalSvc());
    // CComPtr<IMyInterface> intf;
    // HRESULT hr = svc->GetTimeoutObject(&intf);
    // if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
    //     hr = intf->QueryInterface(IID_IUnknown, reinterpret_cast<void**>(ppTimeoutObj));
    // }
    // return hr;
}
```

Also, you also did not show the code that is calling `get_CoreTimeoutObject()`, so we can't determine if *that* caller is leaking or not.